# Way to use bit shift to move decimal place

Tags: nodatime

I am working on a library that needs to do some date math extremely quickly.  I am using Jon Skeet's Noda Time library, which uses Tick math, and so is extremely quick, but I want to get elapsed seconds in a way faster than casting a Noda Time Instant or Duration to a TimeSpan.

The fastest way I have been able to do it so far is using Ticks * 1E-07, but I am thinking that bit shifting might work faster (since it will always be 1E-07).  Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't cast to `TimeSpan` - just take the `Ticks` and divide by `NodaConstants.TicksPerSecond`.  It's an integer division, and likely to be very, very quick. Given that 10<sup>7</sup> isn't a power of two (or particularly neatly represented as combinations of them) I suspect you'd be best off just dividing.

I'd be surprised if this division *really* proved to be a bottleneck in your code. While I'm trying to keep Noda Time quick, I'm not above performing a division or two where appropriate :)

If you need *partial* seconds, I'd be tempted to just divide by `TicksPerMillisecond` instead, and use an integer number of milliseconds rather than using floating-point arithmetic. If you already need a `double` elsewhere, of course, that's not going to help much.

Comment: Strangely, only changing that one part of the calculation (a slope calculation), adds almost a second to the calc time.  That's really strange.  I'm going to mark as an answer because it is a correct answer.

Comment: Also, Noda Time is REALLY fast, so no worries there :). It's much faster than DateTime/TimeSpan/etc.